# where statement breaks full join in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, join

Consider the following tables:

```sql
create table `t1` (
  `date` date,
  `value` int
);

create table `t2` (
  `date` date,
  `value` int
);

insert into `t1` (`date`, `value`)
values ("2022-01-01", 1),
       ("2022-03-01", 3),
       ("2022-04-01", 4);
       
insert into `t2` (`date`, `value`)
values ("2022-01-01", 1),
       ("2022-02-01", 2),
       ("2022-04-01", 4);
```

The `t1` table is missing `2022-02-01` date and `t2` is missing `2022-03-01`. I want to join these two tables so that it produces the following result:

```
| t1.date    | t1.value | t2.date    | t2.value |
|            |          |            |          |
| 2022-01-01 | 1        | 2022-01-01 | 1        |
| null       | null     | 2022-02-01 | 2        |
| 2022-03-01 | 3        | null       | null     |
| 2022-04-01 | 4        | 2022-04-01 | 4        |
```

The solution is a full join:

```sql
select *
from `t1`
left join `t2` on `t2`.`date` = `t1`.`date`

union

select *
from `t1`
right join `t2` on `t2`.`date` = `t1`.`date`;
```

Which produces exactly the result I want. But a `where` statement breaks everything:

```
select *
from `t1`
left join `t2` on `t2`.`date` = `t1`.`date`
where `t1`.`date` > "2022-01-01"

union

select *
from `t1`
right join `t2` on `t2`.`date` = `t1`.`date`
where `t1`.`date` > "2022-01-01";
```

I expected this result:

```
| t1.date    | t1.value | t2.date    | t2.value |
|            |          |            |          |
| null       | null     | 2022-02-01 | 2        |
| 2022-03-01 | 3        | null       | null     |
| 2022-04-01 | 4        | 2022-04-01 | 4        |
```

But I got this:

```
| t1.date    | t1.value | t2.date    | t2.value |
|            |          |            |          |
| 2022-03-01 | 3        | null       | null     |
| 2022-04-01 | 4        | 2022-04-01 | 4        |
```

I think I know what's going on but I can't find a way around it. The problem is that  t1.date > "whatever" filters all empty rows in the `t1` table. I've already tried this but it doesn't work:

```sql
where `t1`.`date` > "2022-01-01" or `t1`.`date` = null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you should use `t2.date > "2022-01-01"` in the right join query.

```
select *
from `t1`
left join `t2` on `t2`.`date` = `t1`.`date`
where `t1`.`date` > "2022-01-01"

union

select *
from `t1`
right join `t2` on `t2`.`date` = `t1`.`date`
where  `t2`.`date` > "2022-01-01";
```

See demo at https://dbfiddle.uk/reo8UanD

Answer (score 1):

> I've already tried this but it doesn't work:
>
> where `t1`.`date` > "2022-01-01" or `t1`.`date` = null

You should use

```
where `t1`.`date` > "2022-01-01" or `t1`.`date` is null
```

"NULL = NULL" results false as the NULL does not have value. Therefore it cannot be the same as any other value (even another NULL). The correct way is to use `is null`

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL to check if a value is null your not gonna use `value = null` but `value IS NULL` or `value IS NOT NULL` if you want to check when the value is assigned.

As the result, you gonna have that:

```sql
WHERE `t1`.`date` > "2022-01-01" OR `t1`.`date` IS NULL
```

In MySQL is proper to write the instructions in uppercase.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've seen some people write instructions in lowercase and I think it's easier to write because I don't have to switch Caps Lock all the time.

Comment: MySQL commands are case insensitive.